# How to throw an exception for closing resource in try with resources?

Tags: exception, try-with-resources

I want to try with resources block(PrintWrtiter or FileWriter) to throw an exception on closing resource, So i can print it.

```
public PrintWriter func throws CustomException{
   String filename = "file.txt";
   try(PrintWriter feedError = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filename , 
                                                                 true))){
       feedError.println("writing in a file");
          return feedError;
       } catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         Throwable[] supp = e.getSuppressed();
         System.Out.Println(supp);
         throw new CustomException("file not found");
        }
    }
```

Expecting `java.lang.Exception`: Error when closing PrintWriter or FileWriter

Comment: What happens when you run the code?  There needs to be an exception in the try block, so the catch block catches it.   You’ll need an invalid file name, a file not found, or some type of error to occur.

Comment: I've tried sending an invalid file name and null string, the code stops execution

Comment: Right after the catch ( Exception e ), put System.out.println( “Error —“ + e.getMessage()  );  You might see the error.

Comment: I just noticed you have quite a few bugs in your code.  This code should not compile.  For example, System.out.printLn () should have lowercase o $out$ and p in $printLn$.  The try block needs to be written try{  } where the code is inside the { }.  The method name needs () after the method name.